# How to select a list of the latest times per day from a list of dates

Tags: c#, linq

That question probably sounded extremely confusing, but it's difficult to describe what I want to do. Basically, I have a list of `DateTime` objects and I want to make a new list that contains the objects from the list that represent the latest time for each date represented in the list. For example, say I have a list containing these `DateTime`s:

- 12/13/2012 2:00:00 AM
- 12/13/2012 4:00:00 AM
- 12/13/2012 8:00:00 PM
- 12/14/2012 5:00:00 PM
- 12/14/2012 3:00:00 AM
- 12/15/2012 10:00:00 AM

I want my results list to contain the following:

- 12/13/2012 8:00:00 PM
- 12/14/2012 5:00:00 PM
- 12/15/2012 10:00:00 AM

I know I can do this using LINQ. I'm just having a hard time trying to wrap my mind around what is happening. I think I have to select from an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<DateTime>>` where the inner `IEnumerable` is a list of `DateTime`s that all have the same date, and then I want to order those by descending and select the first one.

I am quite lost...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dates = list.GroupBy(dt => dt.Date).Select(g => g.Max());
```

Comment: Ok, just so that we're clear. GroupBy returns an `IEnumerable` of groups of dates, and then the following Select returns an `IEnumerable` of the max values from each group?

Comment: Yes, the `Select` will take the maximum value from each `IGrouping<DateTime, DateTime>` (which itself implements `IEnumerable<DateTime>`) returned by the `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
var groups = dateList.GroupBy(date => date.Date)
                     .Select( grp => grp.Max( date => date.TimeOfDay));
```